# Ruby's "foo = true if !defined? foo" won't work as expected

Tags: ruby

When it is in fact not defined, it gets the value `nil` just because it was "touched":

```
$ irb

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo = true if !defined? foo
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo
 => nil 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > if !defined? bar
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  bar = true
ruby-1.9.2-p0 ?>  end
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > bar
 => true
```

so the `if` ... `end` works as expected, but `foo = true if ...` doesn't.

Comment: It's because foo is defined by the time you call `defined?`. I don't see how this is unexpected

Comment: NullUserException: So it doesn't do the 'if' check first? Interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby defines a local variable just before executing a line containing an assignment, so `defined?(foo)` will always be `true` for the one-liner.

Another example showing that local variables are defined before any part of the line are executed:

```
defined? foo # => false
foo = foo    # => foo is now nil
```

Answer (score 1):

it does sound reasonable that 
[statement] if [expression]

is just rearranged by the compiler to

if [expression] then
  [statement]
end

but it looks like it's handled specially in a way which breaks defined? actually, defined looks like a special construct (i.e. not a normal function)

looks like if your assigning it in the same line you should check for .nil? instead:

foo = foo.nil? ? true : foo

(this also works if it's already set to false)

Answer (score 1):

The way to think about this is:

```
foo = (true if !defined? foo)
```

So, first foo is defined, then the expression to give it a value is run.

Comment: this is "to think about it as this way", rather than it actually executing like this?