# Ruby's "foo = true if !defined? foo || foo.nil?" won't work

Tags: ruby

I thought in the following, foo should be true

```
$ irb

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo = true if !defined? foo || foo.nil?
 => nil 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > foo
 => nil
```

because foo was at first not defined, but the `foo = true` part make it temporarily has a nil value, so the `!defined` didn't catch it, but the `foo.nil?` should catch it, and make it true... but why is it still nil?

this is related to [Ruby's "foo = true if !defined? foo" won't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775402/rubys-foo-true-if-defined-foo-wont-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful when skipping parenthesis. You meant:

```
foo = true if !defined?(foo) || foo.nil?
```

As per your other question, the `defined?(foo)` will always be `true`, so really you want to write:

```
foo = true if foo.nil?
```