# Why doesn't this inline if test work?

Tags: ruby

I have an inline if which isn't doing what i thought, and i've distilled it into a console example for clarity.

I thought that the inline if was syntactically the same as the multi-line if, but it looks like it isn't.

```
foo = "chunky"
(bar1 = foo) if (!defined?(bar1) && foo)
bar1
```

In this instance, bar1 ends up set to nil.  If i restructure it to

```
foo = "chunky"
if !defined?(bar2) && foo
  bar2 = foo
end
bar2
```

then it works - bar2 is set to "chunky" (i've used bar2 instead of bar1 in the second example to make sure i was using an undefined variable in each case).

Is it the case that the inline if always sets bar1 to something, defaulting to nil?  I thought it just didn't evaluate the part before the if, if the if test returns falsy.

Comment: Related question (possibly duplicate - can't tell): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775402/rubys-foo-true-if-defined-foo-wont-work-as-expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It fails because as soon as a bareword is seen on the left-hand side of an assignment, it's initialized to `nil`. Thus when you do `(bar1 = foo) if (!defined?(bar1) && foo)`, `bar1` will be `nil` in the `defined?` check. Here's a simplified example:

```
>> defined? foo
=> nil
>> foo = 1 if false
=> nil
>> foo
=> nil
>> defined? foo
=> "local-variable"
```

Comment: This *"If fails because as soon as a bareword is seen on the left-hand side of an assignment, it's initialized to nil."* is a key bit of Ruby knowledge that i was previously missing.  Thanks!